# Hive export table to file with empty cells instead of “NULL”

Tags: hive, hue

I export table from Hive with export->csv/excel, and file contains “NULL” values instead of “, , ,” or empty cells.

Is there a way to export tables without filling empty values by that text?

Comment: Are you using Hue or something else?

Comment: Yes,, I use Hue